# Adding data to data table dependent on prior data

Tags: r, data.table

My first post so hopefully I am doing it right.

I have a table as below:

```
Year    Day Amount
1990    1   200
1990    363 2058
1993    1   10
1993    71  564
1993    360 931
```

I would like to add rows of data to this table such that there is a row entry for all numbers between the maximum 'Day' of each 'Year' in the table and 364, and the corresponding value in 'Amount' would be the maximum 'Amount' for each Year. The resulting data should be:

```
Year    Day Amount
1990    1   200
1990    363 2058
1993    1   10
1993    71  564
1993    360 931
1990    364 2058
1993    361 931
1993    362 931
1993    363 931
1993    364 931
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking advantage of how `data.table[i, j, by]` lets us evaluate expressions in `j` for each group of `by`:

```
library(data.table)


DT <- data.table(
  Year = c(1990, 1990, 1993, 1993, 1993),
  Day  = c(1, 363, 1, 71, 360),
  Amount = c(200, 2058, 10, 564, 931)
)


DT[
  order(Day),
  {
    extended_days <- seq(max(Day) + 1, 364)
    extended_amounts <- rep(max(Amount), length(extended_days))
    list(
      Day = c(Day, extended_days),
      Amount = c(Amount, extended_amounts)
    )
  },
  keyby = Year
]
#     Year Day Amount
#  1: 1990   1    200
#  2: 1990 363   2058
#  3: 1990 364   2058
#  4: 1993   1     10
#  5: 1993  71    564
#  6: 1993 360    931
#  7: 1993 361    931
#  8: 1993 362    931
#  9: 1993 363    931
# 10: 1993 364    931
```